# Dojo's dojo/method programmatically?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a way to define a *dojo/method* programmatically, in a JavaScript function? (Instead of defining it through *script type="dojo/method"* within a declarative widget, for example.)

Comment: Does this http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2007/09/21/dojo-09-power-tools-script-typedojomethod/  do anything for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just override it directly on a widget. For example, if you wrote `dojo/method` for `abc`, do it like that:

```
var myWidget = ...;
myWidget.abc = function(/* args from dojo/method */){
  // the body of dojo/method
};
```

Comment: Any chance you can expand upon this?

Comment: @Sevenearths I don't know what you mean. Adding methods with dojo/method is equivalent with adding them directly to an object (a widget in this case). If you don't know how to get a widget object, just name it with "id" or "widgetId" in HTML, and when their are instantiated call dijit.byId("yourWidgetName") to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the best option in your case is extend widget prototype, do it like that:

```
dojo.require("dijit.OneDijit");
dojo.extend(dijit.OneDijit, {
 newMethod:function(/* method args  */){
 // body of method
 }
});
```